clear coat cement sealer for basement
We are going for an "unfinished" basement look. The picture doesn't do it justice but our cement is in really good condition even though the home is 50 yrs old. The goal is to clear everything out, buff the floor lightly, and put a clear coat on top. Instead of carpet we are going to put down large area rugs for the rooms.

Question:
What kind of clear coat should I put down and can I do it in piece meal or does it have to be one continuous job?

Epoxy finishes are pretty common on concrete.  If you like the concrete look, you can get clear.  Or you can get a near infinite number of color finishes, including many effects.

@Huesmann so the clear coat would still be an epoxy? I was hoping for a finish that still gives more of a concrete feel but it sounds like that's not a possibility.

Don't you already have concrete?  Why finish it with anything, if what you're after is concrete?

@Huesmann We're after the concrete look. Because it's a living space and with concrete being as porous as it is I want to keep kitchen/bathroom spills from working their way into the concrete.

So just use an epoxy clearcoat.

While I was at lowes I realized they have the look on their concrete that I'm going for. They said theirs was buffed real good and that's it. I may go a step further and at a cemet sealer, glossy.

I went with a Valspar "Protective Sealer" with a "Natural Look, Low Gloss". You can't even tell anything is on it until you throw water on it. The water beads up nice but if you leave it long enough (10 minutes?) it will eventually soak ib. It's pretty forgiving to put on and I can always add more coats and if I were to apply it over again I would apply it more liberally.
